# ConnectionString in Azure not overriding LocalSqlServer for Azure Function

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, connection-string, app-config, azure-functions

I find the issue when i run the function app and log the number of connectionstrings available. The only ConnectionString available is the LocalSqlServer, which seem to be a default connectionstring created by the app.

ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Name"].ConnectionString; throws null ref. exception.

ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings[0].Name; gives "LocalSqlServer"

LocalSqlServer ConnectionString:
data source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Integrated Security=SSPI;AttachDBFilename=|DataDirectory|aspnetdb.mdf;User Instance=true

```
<PropertyGroup>
  <TargetFramework>netstandard2.0</TargetFramework>
  <AzureFunctionsVersion>v2</AzureFunctionsVersion>
</PropertyGroup>
<ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions" Version="1.0.10" />
    <PackageReference Include="System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager" Version="4.4.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="System.Linq" Version="4.3.0" />
</ItemGroup>
```

My question is how is it possible to override or disable LocalSqlServer for default database connection and allow the current ConnectionString allready added in the application to show up when running the app?

Edit: 
I was able to use enviroment variables but the issue of using ConnectionStrings from Azure is still an issue.

Comment: ...added in the application where, how?

Comment: I was referring to the application resource in Azure Functions.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How To Access Azure Function App ConnectionString Using dotnet Standard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48048078/how-to-access-azure-function-app-connectionstring-using-dotnet-standard)

Comment: You can always pick it up as an environment variable for simplicity - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/web-sites-configure#connection-strings

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, but as it was only a problem when working in dev I made the following helper method

```
public static class AzureConfigHelper
{
    public static string GetConnectionString(string key)
    {
        // try connection strings first
        if (ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings[key] != null)
        {
            return ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings[key].ConnectionString;
        }
        else
        {
            // If can't locate config in connection strings try environment variables
            return Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable(key);
        }
    }
}`
```

Id like to get a proper solution but I've got more pressing things to work on ~ with this I can use connection strings in prod and environment variables in dev